# How much bigger is 3↑↑↑↑3 compared to 3↑↑↑3?

Tags: big-numbers, hyperoperation

3↑↑↑3 is already mind-bogglingly large, but how much larger is 3↑↑↑↑3? Is it so large that it is simply around 3↑↑↑↑3 times larger than 3↑↑↑3? Or is there another way to express its magnitude in terms of 3↑↑↑3?

Comment: No, it is much much much much much much much much much much much much much much much much much much much much much much much much much much much larger.

Answer (score 1):

By definition, $3\uparrow\uparrow\uparrow\uparrow 3 = 3\uparrow\uparrow\uparrow(3\uparrow\uparrow\uparrow(3\uparrow\uparrow\uparrow 3))$.
\begin{matrix}
   3\uparrow\uparrow\uparrow 3= & \underbrace{3^{3^{3^{3^{\cdot^{\cdot^{\cdot^{\cdot^{3}}}}}}}}} \\
   & \mbox{7,625,597,484,987 copies of 3}
  \end{matrix}

which should make it a little clearer how much bigger $3\uparrow\uparrow\uparrow\uparrow 3$ is than $3\uparrow\uparrow\uparrow 3$. It's hard to even give a more concrete answer because the numbers of powers of $3$ get unreasonably large to compute or type.

Comment: What's the name of the operator?

Comment: I believe it's hyperexponentiation. The symbol is from Knuth's up-arrow notation.

Comment: Correction: $3\uparrow^k3=3\uparrow^{k-1}3\uparrow^{k-1}3$, and generally $a\uparrow^kb=a\uparrow^{k-1}a\uparrow^{k-1}\dots\uparrow^{k-1}a$ with $b$ many $a$'s.

Answer (score 1):

For any integers $B>A>1,$ to gauge "how much bigger is $B$ compared to $A,$" consider the following questions :

1. How many $A$s do we need to **add** together to reach $B$?

   Ans: The least $x$ such that $\underbrace{A+A+...+A}_{x\ A\text{s}}\ge B$, i.e., $A\times x \ge B: \quad x=\left\lceil{B\over A}\right\rceil.$
2. How many $A$s do we need to **multiply** together to reach $B$?

   Ans: The least $x$ such that $\underbrace{A\times A\times...A\times A}_{x\ A\text{s}}\ge B$, i.e., $A\uparrow x\ge B:\quad x=\left\lceil{\log B\over \log A}\right\rceil.$
3. More generally, for any operation $@$ in the [hyperoperation sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperoperation) $(+,\times,\uparrow,\uparrow^2,...)$, we can ask for the least $x$ such that $\underbrace{A@ A@...A@A}_{x\ A\text{s}}\ge B$, i.e., $A@'x\ge B,$ where $@'$ is the next hyperoperation after $@$.

---

Now in the case of $A=3\uparrow^3 3$ and $B=3\uparrow^4 3=3\uparrow^3 A,$ note the following:

$$\begin{align}B &=3\uparrow^4 3\\
&=3\uparrow^3 3\uparrow^3 3\\
&=3\uparrow^3 A\\
&=3\uparrow^2 3\uparrow^3 (A-1)\\
&=3\uparrow^1 3\uparrow^2 (3\uparrow^3 (A-1) - 1)\\
&=3\uparrow^1 3\uparrow^1 3\uparrow^2 (3\uparrow^3 (A-1) - 2)\\
&\\ 
A&=3\uparrow^3 3\\
&=3\uparrow^2 3\uparrow^3 2\\
&=3\uparrow^1 3\uparrow^2 (3\uparrow^3 2 - 1)\\
&=3\uparrow^1 3\uparrow^1 3\uparrow^2 (3\uparrow^3 2 - 2)\\
\end{align}$$

Then the answer to (1) is $x$ such that $A\times x=B$:
$$\begin{align}x={B\over A}={3^{3\uparrow^2 (3\uparrow^3 (A-1) - 1)} \over 3^{3\uparrow^2 (3\uparrow^3 2 - 1)}}=3^{3\uparrow^2 (3\uparrow^3 (A-1) - 1) - 3\uparrow^2 (3\uparrow^3 2 - 1)}.
\end{align}$$

Similarly, the answer to (2) is $x$ such that $A\uparrow x=B$:
$$\begin{align}x&= {\log B\over \log A}={3^{3\uparrow^2 (3\uparrow^3 (A-1) - 2)} \over 3^{3\uparrow^2 (3\uparrow^3 2 - 2)}}=3^{3\uparrow^2 (3\uparrow^3 (A-1) - 2) - 3\uparrow^2 (3\uparrow^3 2 - 2)}.
\end{align}$$

Furthermore, we can give a lower bound on the least $x$ such that $A\uparrow^3 x\ge B$, as we have by [Saibian's inequality](https://drive.google.com/viewerng/viewer?a=v&pid=sites&srcid=ZGVmYXVsdGRvbWFpbnxsYXJnZW51bWJlcnN8Z3g6MzU3Y2U3NjVhMmEyZjY2YQ),
$$(3\uparrow^3 3)\uparrow^3 (3\uparrow^3 3\,-\,3)\ < \ (3)\uparrow^3 (3\uparrow^3 3\,-\,3\,+\,3)\ =\ 3\uparrow^4 3;$$ that is, $$A\uparrow^3 (A-3)=\underbrace{A\uparrow^2 A\uparrow^2 ...A\uparrow^2 A}_{(A-3)\ A\text{s}}< B.$$
Therefore, **$A\uparrow^2 A\uparrow^2 ...A\uparrow^2 A\ge B$ requires more than $(A-3)$ $A$s** on the left-hand side.

(Of course, this is also a lower bound on the least $x$ such that $\underbrace{A\uparrow A\uparrow ...A\uparrow A}_{x\ A\text{s}}=A\uparrow^2 x\ge B.$)

Answer (score 0):

[Knuth's up-arrow notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%27s_up-arrow_notation) is defined so that we have

$$a\uparrow^kb=\underbrace{a\uparrow^{k-1}a\uparrow^{k-1}\dots\uparrow^{k-1}a}_{b\text{ many }a\text{'s}}$$

where $\uparrow^k=\underbrace{\uparrow\uparrow\dots\uparrow\uparrow}_k~$ and we evaluate from right to left (e.g. $a\uparrow b\uparrow c=a\uparrow(b\uparrow c)\ne(a\uparrow b)\uparrow c$ in general).

This means we have:

$$3\uparrow\uparrow\uparrow\uparrow3=3\uparrow\uparrow\uparrow3\uparrow\uparrow\uparrow3$$

and we also have

$$3\uparrow\uparrow\uparrow3=3\uparrow\uparrow3\uparrow\uparrow3\uparrow\uparrow3$$

and

$$3\uparrow\uparrow3=3\uparrow3\uparrow3=3^{3^3}=7,625,597,484,987$$

Using this result, we may further calculate $3\uparrow\uparrow\uparrow3$ as

$$\underbrace{3^{3^{3^{.^{.^.}}}}}_{7,625,597,484,987}$$

which is pretty large. Keep in mind that this is $3\uparrow\uparrow\uparrow3$, or $3\uparrow\uparrow3\uparrow\uparrow3$. If we took this result and did $\uparrow\uparrow$ that many times, we'd basically arrive at $3\uparrow\uparrow\uparrow\uparrow3$, which is equivalent to:

$$3\uparrow\uparrow\uparrow3\uparrow\uparrow\uparrow3=\underbrace{3\uparrow\uparrow3\uparrow\uparrow\dots\uparrow\uparrow3}_{3\uparrow\uparrow\uparrow3}$$

which is much much much larger compared to the relatively puny

$$3\uparrow\uparrow\uparrow3=\underbrace{3\uparrow\uparrow3\uparrow\uparrow3}_3$$

Answer (score -1):

3^^^3 is equal to 3^^3^^3 which is equal to 3^^(3^3^3) 
3^^(3^3^3)= 3^^(3^27)= 3^^(7.6 trillion)= 3^3^3^3... 7.6 trillion times.
Let's represent this mind boggling number as x.

3^^^^3 is equal to 3^^^3^^^3 which is equal to 3^^^(x)
which is equal to 3^^3^^3^^3...(with x ^^3's)
Two threes: 3^^3 is around 7.6 trillion
Three threes: 3^^3^^3= x
Four threes: 3^^3^^3^^3= 3^3^3...(with x ^3's)
At five threes I can't even list out the exponentiation.

You get how if there were, say, a googleplex threes all tetrated, it would be completely absurd.

But we know that x is far far far (and I can not stress this enough) far far larger than a googleplex, or even a number with a googleplex digits.

In conclusion:
3^^^^3= 3^^^3^^^3
=3^^3^^3^^3...(with x 3's)
And because at even just 3^^3^^3^^3^^3 I can't list out the exponentiation, it is impossible to do so with x 3's.

So yes, 3^^^^3 is so large it is simply around just 3^^^^3 times larger than 3^^^3.

(although it really is just 3^^^3^^^3.)